# Does exist SFF-8087 adapters to PCIe?

Tags: supermicro, pci-express, u.2

I've found a few adapters from SFF-8642/8639/8611 to PCI express.

Is it possible to do the same with a SFF-8087? Either directly or adapting to an intermediate format and then to PCI express?

I have a couple SFF-8087 which are just wasted in my Supermicro motherboard (H11DSI).

Kind regards,

Comment: Can you provide much more context, description and information? As far as I understand from [specs](https://members.snia.org/document/dl/26427) SFF-8642 is about connectors. Whereby Peripheral Component Interconnect Express (PCIe) is the Standard Specification and used mostly as or in motherboards to connect with the chipset. So for me it is unclear what to you try to connect with what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, SFF-8087 is a connector used for SAS exclusively. You cannot "adapt" it to PCIe because the SFF-8087 port on your motherboard literally does not go to PCIe lanes directly – it only goes to a SAS disk controller, just like the SATA ports on a PC go to a SATA controller.

(While PCIe is general-purpose and can be "adapted" to become a SAS/SATA/USB port by connecting an appropriate SAS/SATA/USB controller in the middle, the reverse is not true; an adapter cannot bypass the SAS/SATA/USB controller that's already there, unless it was specifically designed for. USB has Thunderbolt for this kind of "bypass directly to PCIe", SAS/SATA generally do not.)

This is different from e.g. SFF-8639 (U.2), which is a connector that *does* typically provide PCIe lanes from the beginning, just in a different shape, so of course there are adapters that just convert it from one form-factor to another (the same way as M.2 "NVMe" slots are really just PCIe slots and have adapters both ways).